# List Problems in 1 Dimensional Python Battleship

Tags: python, arrays

I'm just starting to learn python and have come across some trouble when trying to program a simple 1-D version of single player battleship.

2 things I can't seem to make work:

1. I have a created a 1 dimensional list (which is the gameplay board), but need to display/print the indices of the repeating element of the list. In other words, how can I print a list that only shows the indices of the elements in my board?
2. I want to replace a that element with a "*" if it was a wrong guess. For example, if I wrongly guess the position as 4 in a board of 5 elements, I want to display:

   `1 2 3 * 5`

Moreover, I want to display the winning hit as an "X":

```
1 2 X * 5
```

Here's my current code:

```
from random import randint

ship=randint(0, 5)
board = ["O","O","O","O","O"]

print ("Let's play Battleship!")

attempts = 1
while attempts < 4:
    print (board)
    guess = int(input("Guess Where My Ship Is: "))
    if guess == ship:
        print ("Congratulations Captain, you sunk my battleship!")
        break
    else:
        print ("You missed my battleship!")
        if attempts<3:
            print("Try again!")
        elif attempts==3:
            print("Better luck next time, Captain!")

    attempts+=1
```

Thank you and apologies for the lame question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice: set the board size to a variable so you can reference it regularly. Put this at the top

```
size = 5 # Can be changed later if you want to make the board bigger
```

Next, have your ship location be chosen based on that

```
ship = randint(0, size)
```

Instead of making a board filled with 0's, Generate the board dynamically so that it's already pre-populated with the possible values.

```
board = [] # Creating an empty board
for i in range(1, size):
  position = str(i) # Converting integers to strings
  board.append(position) # Adding those items to the board
```

Then, inside of the game logic, after the "You missed my battleship" line, change the relevant square on the board

```
...
print("You missed my battleship!")
number_guess = int(guess) - 1 # Because lists are zero-indexed
board[number_guess] = "*" # Assign "*" to the spot that was guessed
if attempts < 3:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it and I'm trying to implement a similar method to get the Hits shown as well. I like the dynamic board a lot more, but for future reference, is it possible to represent a board of elements by indices?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you mean by "represent by indices"

If you mean "print out a list's indices rather than its values" then that can be accomplished with this monstrosity print(list(range(0,len(board))). Going from inside out, the len grabs the length of the board. The range makes a range between 0 and that number. The list converts that range into a list, and print prints it out. 

However, I don't think that's what you're looking for, since that wouldn't display which spaces have been turned into "*"s. Can you elaborate a bit on what you want the output to be?

Comment: Couldn't you do the same thing with enumerate? I just coded a few extra lines that allowed me to do this: for index,y in enumerate(board): print(index,end=" "). This gave me the indices for the elements in the original board that was represented by "O"s.  The problem is, I can't get this newly represented list to print instead of the "O"s one. I want to do this so that I can dynamically represent the board in fancier ways, for example, placing boxes around the numbers so that it looks more like a gaming interface. Sorry, I'm not sure I'm being coherent here.

Answer (score 2):

To implement your two display functionalities, I would recommend just letting your `board` list just hold the display values, as you're not using it anywhere else anyway.

```
from random import randint

ship=randint(1, 5)
board = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

print ("Let's play Battleship!")

attempts = 1
while attempts < 4:
    print(' '.join(board))
    guess = int(input("Guess Where My Ship Is: "))
    if guess == ship:
        print ("Congratulations Captain, you sunk my battleship!")
        board[guess - 1] = 'X'
        break
    else:
        print ("You missed my battleship!")
        board[guess - 1] = '*'
        if attempts<3:
            print("Try again!")
        elif attempts==3:
            print("Better luck next time, Captain!")
    attempts+=1

print(' '.join(board))
```

One more thing: You have a bug when you're selecting the index of the ship (should be in range [1, 5]), which I've also corrected.

In case you're expanding on your battleship program and you must have a function that prints out the indices of a list (unless the value is `'*'` or `'X'`), one way is to simply do:

```
def display(b):
    print(' '.join(y if y in 'X*' else str(x + 1) for x, y in enumerate(b)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nicely dynamic and clean; didn't notice the bug - I guess I don't have an eye for these things just yet. Displaying the values on its own is a lot more convenient, but for curiosity's sake, is it possible to represent a board of elements by indices?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to print out the indices of a list in the way you intend. I will update my answer.